# How to wrap labels and left align them to the right

Tags: user-interface, gwt, alignment

I have this code

```
HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
hp.setWith("100%");
hp.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
hp.add(new Label("label 1"));
hp.add(new Anchor("anchor 1"));
hp.add(new Label("label 2"));
hp.add(new Anchor("Anchor 2"));
RootPanel.get().add(hp);
```

Actually it displays

> label1...........................................anchor1......................................label2..................................anchor2

I actually wanted something like

> label1 anchor1 label2 anchor2

Is there a layout for that or other solution ?
thx

Comment: This will work if you don't set your horizontal panels width to anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your `HorizontalPanel`, but try this:

```
HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
hp.setHorizontalAlignment(HasAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
hp.setSpacing(2); // 2 = number of pixels between each item
hp.add(new Label("label 1"));
hp.add(new Anchor("anchor 1"));
hp.add(new Label("label 2"));
hp.add(new Anchor("Anchor 2"));
RootPanel.get().add(hp);
```

All you really needed was a setSpacing property so they're not literally attached to the next cell in your `hp`, and to remove the `hp.setWidth("100%")`. If you were doing this in UiBinder, you could keep the 100% width and set the width of each `<g:cell>` independently, allowing more flexibility.

Also, I suggest you use `HasAlignment` over `HasHorizontalAlignment` and/or `HasVerticalAlignment`, if for no other reason than `HasAlignment` is portable to all types of panels.

Answer (score 0):

Try FlowPanel.  It simply adds widgets from left to right, no spacing, and wraps at the end of the line.

Maybe I'm missing something.  It there something more to the layout that you want?

Comment: I updated my question, because with a FlowPanel, I can have labels horizontally but when I add Anchor and Label for example, it displays the elements vertically

Comment: setting your elements display to inline should solve the displaying vertical issue. For instance; `label.getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Display.INLINE);`

Comment: The solution given by pistolPanties worked for me, I put the style in a CSS

.div_horizontal{
 display: inline;
}

Comment: @Moh You don't have to use the CSS style if you use an InlineLabel instead of a regular Label.